# LMFIT: Constraining the output when using the polynomial model

Tags: python, constraints, curve-fitting, lmfit, piecewise

I'm using LMFIT to fit a piecewise polynomials to the first quadrant of a sine wave.
I would like to be able to add a constraint on the polynomial output - as opposed to on its parameters.
For example, I would like to ensure that the output is >= 0 and <= 1.0 (which of course only affects the first and last segment in the code below).
Another use case if if I want the polynomial to pass through some specific (x,y) exact points.

I understand this might be better done with np.polyfit but eventually I want to add more non-linear constraints and the LMFIT framework is more flexible.

```
import numpy as np
from lmfit.models import LinearModel

#split sine wave in 4 segments with 1024 points
nseg = 4
frac = 2**10
npoints = nseg*frac
xfrac = np.linspace(0, 1, num=frac, endpoint=False)
x = np.linspace(0, 1, num=npoints, endpoint=False)
y = np.sin(x*np.pi/2)
yseg = np.reshape(y, (nseg, frac))


mod = LinearModel()

coeff = []
bestfit = []
for i in range(nseg):
    pars = mod.guess(yseg[i], x=xfrac)
    out = mod.fit(yseg[i], pars, x=xfrac)
    coeff.append([out.best_values['slope'], out.best_values['intercept']])
    bestfit.append(out.best_fit)
bestfit = np.reshape(bestfit, (1, npoints))[0]
```

Comment: I can only see how constraints can be added on model parameters and not its output (here the result of y=mx+b in each segment)

Comment: Am i right in saying that your piece-wise function is not continuous? Concerning the restrictions on the output parameters I guess you have to manually calculate the according limits for the input parameters.

Comment: You are right it's not continuous. Enforcing continuity doesn't seem to be a generic constraint so I suppose the same idea as posted below need to be done.

Comment: Well you could try something in the sense of linear B-splines

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is done by adding constraints on the parameters themselves that turns into the right constraint on the model output.
Using a custom model for linear interpolation it can be done as following:

```
        def func(x, c0, c1):
            return c0 + c1*x
        pmodel = Model(func)
        params = Parameters()
        params.add('c0')
        params.add('clip', value=0, max=1.0, vary=True)
        params.add('c1', expr='clip-c0')
```

Answer (score 0):

One option might be using splines.
A quick and dirty approach, just to present the idea, might look like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

## quich and dirty spline function
def l_spline(x, abc ):
    if isinstance( x, ( list, tuple, np.ndarray ) ):
        out = [ l_spline( elem, abc ) for elem in x]
    else:
        a, b, c = abc
        if x < a:
            f = lambda t: 0
        elif x < b:
            f = lambda t: ( t - a ) / ( b - a )
        elif x < c:
            f = lambda t: -( t - c ) / (c - b )
        else:
            f = lambda t: 0
        out = f(x)
    return out

### test data
xl = np.linspace( 0, 4, 150 )
sl = np.fromiter( ( np.sin( elem ) for elem in xl ), np.float )

### test splines with manual double knots on first and last
yl = dict()
yl[0] = l_spline( xl, ( 0, 0, .4 ) )
for i in range(1, 10 ):
    yl[i] = l_spline( xl, ( (i - 1 ) * 0.4 , i * 0.4, (i + 1 ) * 0.4 ) )
yl[10] = l_spline( xl, ( 3.6, 4, 4 ) )


## This is the most simple linear least square for the coefficients

AT = list()
for i in range( 11 ):
    AT.append( yl[i] )
AT = np.array( AT )
A = np.transpose( AT )

U = np.dot( AT, A )
UI = np.linalg.inv( U )
K = np.dot( UI, AT )
v = np.dot( K, sl )


## adding up the weigthed sum
out = np.zeros( len( sl ) )
for a, l in zip( v, AT ):
    out += a * l

### plotting
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1 )
ax.plot( xl, sl, ls=':' )
for i in range( 11 ):
    ax.plot( xl, yl[i] )
ax.plot( xl, out, color='k')
plt.show()
```

Looks like this:
[image: spline fit]

Instead of the simple linear optimization one could use more complex functions to ensure that no parameter is larger than 1. This automatically ensures that the function does not go beyond 1. A fixed point can be established by setting the according b-spline to a fixed value, i.e. not fitting its parameter.